# Some advice on e-commerce ASP.NET Solution

Tags: asp.net, e-commerce

Starting to do some work on an online gifts website. I have not worked on an e-commerce solution before. What I need from the solution is:

- The store front in MVC2 pattern.
  Build from scratch is fine. (desirable)
- Complete UI Independence -  The user 
  interface would use a lot of AJAX and
  jQuery. (very imp)
- Paypal, Autherize.Net and other major    payment gateways
  compatibility. (desirable)
- Fast data access (very imp).
- Modest learning curve and good documentation. (desirable)
- Customizable (more than desirable)

NOPCommerce seems to be the only widely used open source solution. I am not very sure how well it scores on the above mentioned points. The documentation is $20.

Also heard a lot of good things about http://www.aspdotnetstorefront.com/ but its pretty expensive with $1250 cost per license.

Some e-commerce solution would definitely be required to save development time for database and admin screens. So need some good recommendations on this part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems just you asked too much from a single project, I assumed that you are looking for an open source solution.

nopCommerce has lots of payment service integration but it is ASP.NET Webform, not MVC.

I worked with AspDotNetStoreFront last year and also took a glance at its code, all I can say about it is big and complex, and definitely it is not for people who is new to ecommerce solutions.

The quickest way is to search for various keywords in CodePlex such as "ecommerce", "paypal", "authorize.net", surely you will find several ecommerce solutions and they are altogether can fulfill most of your requirements.

Comment: Thanks. How about I use the nopCommerce database and classes provided and go ahead with the MVC2 implementation?

Comment: Reusing database and business logic classes should help but I have never known anyone who used nopCommerce in this way. Firstly, you'd better to buy their nopCommerce guide document to understand it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Rob Conery's ASP.NET MVC Storefront series of screencast tutorials:

http://blog.wekeroad.com/category/mvc-storefront